# qty on had does not show item in 0

Tags: sql-server

My problem is that I have to display qty on hand + qty allocated + qty back ordered.

with the query that I have it displays everything exept for the qty on hand that is in 0 .  this the query that I have:

```
SELECT item_location_view.item_id AS 'Item',
item_location_view.item_desc AS 'Description',
inv_mast.class_id1 AS 'Brand', 
item_location_view.location_id AS 'Location', 
item_location_view.qty_on_hand AS 'Qty on Hand',
item_location_view.qty_allocated AS 'Qty Allocated',
item_location_view.qty_on_po AS 'Qty on PO', 
item_location_view.qty_backordered AS 'Qty Backordered',
qty_on_hand-qty_allocated AS 'Qty Available',
item_location_view.moving_average_cost AS 'Cost', 
item_location_view.price1 AS 'Price', 
item_location_view.purchase_discount_group AS 'Group', 
item_location_view.product_group_id AS 'Product Group', 
item_location_view.product_group_desc AS 'Prod Group Description', 
item_location_view.last_purchase_date AS 'Last Purchase Date', 
inv_mast.weight AS 'Cube Master Pack',
inv_mast.net_weight AS 'Cube',
inv_mast.cube AS 'Weight', 
inv_mast.purchasing_weight AS 'Purchasing Volume'
dbo.inv_mast inv_mast, 
dbo.item_location_view_item_location_view
WHERE inv_mast.item_id = item_location_view.item_id AND       ((item_location_view.location_id<$300) AND (item_location_view.qty_on_hand=>$0 and item_location_view.qty_allocated >0 and item_location_view.qty_backordered >0))
ORDER BY item_location_view.item_id
```

Comment: Are you sure this is for SQL Server?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Where is your FROM clause? And like the guy said above, is this for MSSQL?

Comment: I *expect* the problem is in the clause `(item_location_view.qty_on_hand=>$0 and item_location_view.qty_allocated >0 and item_location_view.qty_backordered >0)` - the greater-than-or-equal-to operator is `>=` and why are you using money amounts (e.g. `$0`) for an integer?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I do not know what append when I paste the query. the from did not paste. the >= i make a mistake and I corrected. with $ I need to used and I do not know why our database require it.

Comment: @CamiloEcheverry 1) There are SQL formatting websites - maybe you could use one of them to format your SQL to edit your question so that the essential part does not need scrolling to see it. 2) Can `item_location_view.qty_on_hand` ever be negative? If not, then you should remove that part. 3) If there is a reason that `item_location_view.qty_on_hand` is a `money` datatype instead of an `int`, please edit your question to include the reason, or go and ask someone why that happened.